# What is difference between Module Loader and Module Bundler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, module

Can someone provide some information about Module Loaders and Module Bundlers in JavaScript?

- What are the differences?
- When should I use a Module Loader and when a Module Bundler?
- Why do we need them at all?

Comment: @JKL I know my answer is late, but take a look if it's helpful.

Answer (score 70):

Module loaders and bundlers both make it more actionable to write modular JavaScript applications. Let me give you some background:

**Module loaders**

A module loader is typically some library that can load, interpret and execute JavaScript modules you defined using a certain module format/syntax, such as [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) or [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/).

When you write modular JavaScript applications, you usually end up having one file per module. So when writing an application that consist of hundreds of modules it could get quite painful to make sure all files are included and in the correct order. So basically a loader will take care of the dependency management for you, by making sure all modules are loaded when the application is executed. Checkout some popular module loaders such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) to get an idea.

**Module bundlers**

Module bundlers are an alternative to module loaders. Basically they do the same thing (manage and load interdependent modules), but do it as part of the application build rather than at runtime. So instead of loading dependencies as they appear when your code is executed, a bundler stitches together all modules into a single file (a bundle) before the execution. Take a look at [Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) as two popular options.

**When to use what?**

Which one is better simply depends on your application's structure and size.

The primary advantage of a bundler is that it leaves you with far fewer files that the browser has to download. This can give your application a performance advantage, as it *may* decrease the amount of time it takes to load.
*However*, depending on the number of modules your application has, this doesn't always have to be the case. Especially for big apps a module loader can sometimes provide the better performance, as loading one huge monolithic file can also block starting your app at the beginning. So that is something you have to simply test and find out.

**ES6/ES2015 Update**

Note that ECMAScript 2015 (or ES6) comes with it's own, native implementation of modules. You can get a quick intro [here](https://v8.dev/features/modules) and [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/).

Comment: Really helpful to see all the above in the same place. Do you think it's worth adding [Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org)?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that with tools like Webpack, one can leverage _Code Splitting_ which allows splitting code into chunks loaded on-demand and thus alleviating the issue of a single monolithic file being produced. https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: Does it make sense to look into ES6 modules if you want to support ES5? I think you can transpile them, correct?

Comment: Great summary, so thankful you ignored Jaromanda X.

Comment: maybe also mention umd? https://dev.to/iggredible/what-the-heck-are-cjs-amd-umd-and-esm-ikm

Answer (score -1):

**Module Loaders**

In JavaScript, module loaders are tools or mechanisms that allow you to load and manage modules, which are reusable pieces of code. Modules enable you to organize your code into smaller, more manageable files, and they encourage code reuse.

Common JS - Module format designed for Nodejs or server side

Asynchronous Module Definition AMD - Module format designed for the browser or client side. However, it's not as popular as it once was and has been largely superseded by ES6 Modules for modern front-end development.

ES6 Modules - With the introduction of ES6, you can use imports and exports which support both client and server side. It is widely used in both browser and server side environments. They are considered standard in modern JS applications.

System JS - SystemJS is a module loader that loads modules dynamically in the browser. It supports various module formats, including CommonJS, AMD, and ES6 Modules (ESM).

**Module Bundlers**

Module bundlers in JavaScript help developers manage and bundle modules and dependencies in their JavaScript applications. They take multiple JavaScript files and their dependencies, combine them into a single file (or multiple files), and optimize them for production use.

Most commonly used module bundlers are

Webpack : It is one of the most popular bundlers on the market. It can handle not only CommonJs / AMD but also ES6 with appropriate plugins.

Rollup : It is one of the most optimized bundlers known for tree-shaking

Parcel : It is a zero config bundler that simplifies the bundling process

Browserify : It is one of the oldest bundlers

Requirejs : It is primarily an AMD loader

On answering the above explanation

**What are the differences?**

Both serve different purposes and are not comparable

When should I use a Module Loader and when a Module Bundler?

Module loaders are used when loading modules into your project. Whereas module bundlers can be used to create modules in different formats

Why do we need them at all?

Both of these can be combined to increase collaboration in development and reduce development efforts and promote reusability. A quick summary of Why code modularization is important?

Abstraction

Encapsulation

Reusability and more...

Module bundlers allow us to manage and optimize these dependencies.